# move object on x axis with animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I want to move the gameobject on x axis with animation. I wrote below code but it only works if i clear input.getkeydown condition. Is there a way to do that with if the key is pressed?
Thanks

```
void Update()
 {

     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
     {
         float delta = speed * Time.deltaTime;
         Vector3 currentPosition = gameObject.transform.position;
         Vector3 nextPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPosition, new Vector3(center, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), delta);

         // Move the object to the next position
         Debug.Log("delta" + delta);
         Debug.Log("nextposition x" + nextPosition.x.ToString());
         gameObject.transform.position = nextPosition;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply record the animation fram by fram in unity then play the animation on awake or using the trigger method using the script

Comment: can you explain me more about this

Comment: I just want to change the x transform of the object with animation. and I wrote the code in the question but it works if there is no if condition in the update method.

Comment: you can visit the link: https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/s/animation